# Calculate rolling average on non consecutive rows of panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, exponential

I am working with a panda data frame of 5 min bars and closing prices. I'd like to calculate a rolling EMA for different time frames. To do the 5 min ema, this works: `df['close'].ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()`

However, to do a rolling 20 min EMA of span 10 seems very difficult. I would need to subset each minute into groups of twenty minutes, for example, 9:30, 9:50, 10:10..., then 9:35, 9:55, 10:15... and then calculate the EMA on this subset and finally merge back at the end. Since these are 5 min bars, there will be 12 subsets to do.

Said another way, I would like to calculate a rolling EMA on non-consecutive rows. Using the index instead of the date, I would want the EMA of rows, 0,4,8,12...76, then rows 1,5,9,13...77 and so on.

Is there an easier way to do this?

The data frame is below, I am sorry I cannot get it into a format to cut and paste into a console. json.dumps() says Timestamps are not JSON serializable.

Thank you.

```
    date    close
0   2019-08-21 09:30:00 292.26
1   2019-08-21 09:35:00 292.31
2   2019-08-21 09:40:00 292.77
3   2019-08-21 09:45:00 292.6
4   2019-08-21 09:50:00 292.63
5   2019-08-21 09:55:00 292.53
6   2019-08-21 10:00:00 292.48
7   2019-08-21 10:05:00 292.34
8   2019-08-21 10:10:00 292.18
9   2019-08-21 10:15:00 292.38
10  2019-08-21 10:20:00 292.4
11  2019-08-21 10:25:00 292.33
12  2019-08-21 10:30:00 292.19
13  2019-08-21 10:35:00 292.06
14  2019-08-21 10:40:00 292.04
15  2019-08-21 10:45:00 292.18
16  2019-08-21 10:50:00 292.32
17  2019-08-21 10:55:00 292.3
18  2019-08-21 11:00:00 292.28
19  2019-08-21 11:05:00 292.57
20  2019-08-21 11:10:00 292.55
21  2019-08-21 11:15:00 292.47
22  2019-08-21 11:20:00 292.47
23  2019-08-21 11:25:00 292.49
24  2019-08-21 11:30:00 292.63
25  2019-08-21 11:35:00 292.76
26  2019-08-21 11:40:00 292.72
27  2019-08-21 11:45:00 292.59
28  2019-08-21 11:50:00 292.55
29  2019-08-21 11:55:00 292.75
30  2019-08-21 12:00:00 292.63
31  2019-08-21 12:05:00 292.57
32  2019-08-21 12:10:00 292.64
33  2019-08-21 12:15:00 292.52
34  2019-08-21 12:20:00 292.43
35  2019-08-21 12:25:00 292.46
36  2019-08-21 12:30:00 292.46
37  2019-08-21 12:35:00 292.46
38  2019-08-21 12:40:00 292.47
39  2019-08-21 12:45:00 292.5
40  2019-08-21 12:50:00 292.64
41  2019-08-21 12:55:00 292.59
42  2019-08-21 13:00:00 292.63
43  2019-08-21 13:05:00 292.64
44  2019-08-21 13:10:00 292.59
45  2019-08-21 13:15:00 292.61
46  2019-08-21 13:20:00 292.61
47  2019-08-21 13:25:00 292.54
48  2019-08-21 13:30:00 292.43
49  2019-08-21 13:35:00 292.48
50  2019-08-21 13:40:00 292.42
51  2019-08-21 13:45:00 292.46
52  2019-08-21 13:50:00 292.4
53  2019-08-21 13:55:00 292.32
54  2019-08-21 14:00:00 292.47
55  2019-08-21 14:05:00 292.37
56  2019-08-21 14:10:00 292.26
57  2019-08-21 14:15:00 292.57
58  2019-08-21 14:20:00 292.45
59  2019-08-21 14:25:00 292.58
60  2019-08-21 14:30:00 292.37
61  2019-08-21 14:35:00 292.05
62  2019-08-21 14:40:00 292.15
63  2019-08-21 14:45:00 291.88
64  2019-08-21 14:50:00 291.89
65  2019-08-21 14:55:00 292.0
66  2019-08-21 15:00:00 291.96
67  2019-08-21 15:05:00 292.15
68  2019-08-21 15:10:00 292.14
69  2019-08-21 15:15:00 292.28
70  2019-08-21 15:20:00 292.23
71  2019-08-21 15:25:00 292.25
72  2019-08-21 15:30:00 292.39
73  2019-08-21 15:35:00 292.36
74  2019-08-21 15:40:00 292.35
75  2019-08-21 15:45:00 292.27
76  2019-08-21 15:50:00 292.38
77  2019-08-21 15:55:00 292.43
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a grouping key and then just df.groupby(key).rolling().mean()

e.g. for a rolling mean of every 4th row

```
df['mod_4'] = df.index % 4
df['rolling_mean_4'] df.groupby(['mod_4']).mean()
```

see also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html